# Augmented image getting detected but not tracked

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am working on augmented image example in arcore where I am able to detect the image but the image is not getting tracked and the object is not getting placed.I am referring augmented image example from codelabs. I have changed the image (hand made image), whose arcoreimg score in 100 and also done following changes to the code. It's getting detected continuously but not tracked.

```
config.setUpdateMode(Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);
config.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
```

Answer (score 2):

> For successive detection and tracking of Augmented Images in ARCore follow these basic rules:

- In ARCore 1.15+, if your image doesn't move (like a poster on a wall), you should attach a **`global anchor`** to the image to increase the tracking's stability.
- The physical image has to occupy 1/4 of the camera feed.
- The smallest image resolution should be 300 x 300 pixels.
- You must track your image under appropriate lighting conditions. Barely-lit room is not good environment for AR user experience.
- It's much better to specify an expected physical size of a tracked image. Additional metadata improves tracking performance, especially for large physical images (more than 75 cm in size).
- When ARCore detected a desired image with no expected physical size specified, its **tracking state will be automatically paused**. For user it means that ARCore has recognised the image, but hasn't gathered enough data to estimate its location in 3D space. **`Do not use the image's pose and size estimates until the image's tracking state is tracking`**.
- Augmented Images support `.png` and `.jpeg`. However, avoid heavy compression for `.jpeg`.
- Use images with a high contrast content, it's no matter whether they are color or black-and-white.
- Avoid images with repetitive patterns (like `Polka dot`) and sparse features.

Answer (score 1):

Andy's answer is correct, but maybe insufficiently specific.  I had this issue as well and as soon as I added an expected width in meters, it started working almost immediately.

Instead of `augmentedImageDatabase.addImage(DEFAULT_IMAGE_NAME, augmentedImageBitmap);`

Use `augmentedImageDatabase.addImage(DEFAULT_IMAGE_NAME, augmentedImageBitmap, <width in meters>);`

Then it'll start tracking almost as soon as it is detected and you won't have to deal with this paused shenanigans.  Worked great for me with a 7cm image with a 95 score.  It even works great with an image with a score of 40.  40 score image with a set width works better than 100 score image without a set width.